# In which year(s) could I have been born, if you know my unexact age in an unexactly dated source (unexact means exact up untill years)

Tags: calculation-puzzle

At some point in 2015 I filled out a form and wrote 41 for my age.
**What are my possible birth years?**

Some trivial clarification about the information above:

- The age 41 is only exact up until the *year* of age. In other words: it can refer to **any age** between **41 years, 0 months, 0 days** and **1 minute before I turned 42!**

Comment: Could this be more simply worded as 
"At some point in 2015 I filled out a form and wrote 41 for my age. What are my possible birth years?"

Comment: It certainly can. It's possible to change the idiom "report" to "form", and to simplify some grammatical structures. I wonder why people down-vote this question: perhaps because the answer requires more thinking than one might hope for?

Comment: It is fairly awkwardly worded as is and hard to understand, it took me a few readings to figure out what you meant. maybe if you simplify it, it will help.

Comment: Simplified according to your advice. Thanks @JohnMeacham

Comment: @Deusovi - So, is it possible to migrate this question to Mathematics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $D$ is the <del>date</del> instant at which your age was reported,
$$D\ge\text{2015-01-01 00:00:00}\tag1$$
$$D<\text{2016-01-01 00:00:00}\tag2$$
because $D$ is in 2015. 
If $B$ is the instant of your birth, then your age was $D-B$, so
$$D-B\ge41\tag3$$ $$D-B<42\tag4$$
Or equivalently,
$$B-D\le-41\tag5$$ $$B-D>-42\tag6$$

> Adding inequalities $1$ and $6$, we get
> $$\begin{align}D&\ge\text{2015-01-01 00:00:00}\tag1\\+~~~~~~B-D&>-42\tag6\\ \hline B&>\text{1973-01-01 00:00:00}\end{align}$$
> And adding inequalities $2$ and $5$, we get
> $$\begin{align}D&<\text{2016-01-01 00:00:00}\tag2\\+~~~~~~B-D&\le-41\tag5\\ \hline B&<\text{1975-01-01 00:00:00}\end{align}$$
>
> So $B$ (the moment of your birth) must be > the beginning of 1973
> and < the beginning of 1975; i.e,
> $$\bbox[5px, border:1px solid]{\text{it must have been in 1973 or 1974.}}$$
>
> We can verify this with a sanity check: if you were born before 1973
> (even if it was late in the evening of 1972-12-31),
> you turned 42 on 2014-12-31 or earlier,
> and so you were not 41 at any time in 2015. 
> Conversely, if you were born after 1974
> (even if it was early in the morning of 1975-01-01),
> you didn’t *turn 41* until 2016-01-01 or later,
> and so you were not 41 at any time in 2015.

Comment: Nicely laid out, even though this puzzle was (perhaps overzealously) eliminated mathematically